# Automotive: Can we design a secured PDU which is beyond 8 bytes and send it using CAN TP?

Tags: security, protocols, can-bus, automotive, communication-protocol

The existing frames are designed to have the signals with some E2E protection, it is now identified that these signals also need a secoc protection. Without re-designing the frames, can i create a secured pdu and send this with CAN TP? If so how do i segment this pdu. I am having this question only because the current supported protocol is CAN. The solution for CAN FD or ethernet would have been pretty straight forward.

I am using PREEvision to design the communication